# Insert values with single quotation in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I want to run the following query with a single quoted value.

```
INSERT INTO web_camp_keywords (web_id, keyword) VALUES (195, 'abc'hotels')
```

I just want to add `abc'hotels` value. I used backslash, but it did not work.

```
INSERT INTO web_camp_keywords (web_id, keyword) VALUES (195, 'abc\'hotels')
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: try INSERT INTO web_camp_keywords (web_id, keyword) VALUES (195, 'abc''hotels')
. but why not prepared statement?

Comment: tnx. I have not experence about prepared statement. I'll try that.

Comment: @Asurya then your application is FULL of what are called SQL injection security holes. Imagine what happens if the user who entered `abc'hotels` into a form instead entered `abc'; DELETE FROM web_camp_keywords;--` or worse, `abc';DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;--` ? *splat*, there goes your entire database. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection (*Note: The `DROP SCHEMA` trick shouldn't work if your app connects with only the minimum required permissions - it shouldn't own the tables or be a superuser - but your app is probably the owner of the tables.*)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can escape the single quote with another single.

```
INSERT INTO web_camp_keywords (web_id, keyword) 
VALUES (195, 'abc''hotels')
```

But personally I think you should be using [prepared statements with bind parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Among other things, use of prepared statements with bind parameters is one of the easiest ways to help protect against [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), the biggest source of security holes in web applications.

Answer (score 2):

Like Chris Moutray and others mentioned, it would be best if you used pdo and prepared statements. Here is an example on how you could prepare a statement, provide the statement with values and then execute it. I left out the connection.

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("insert into web_camp_keywords (web_id, keyword) values (:id, :keyword)");
$statement->bindValue(':id', 195);
$statement->bindValue(':keyword', "abc'hotels");
$statement->execute();
```